# Does Trello keep logs of IP addresses every time someone signs in an account?

Tags: trello, privacy

Does Trello keep logs of IP addresses every time someone signs in an account?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Trello's Privacy Policy](https://trello.com/privacy), Yes:

> When you use the Services, we also collect potentially personally identifying information in the form of Internet Protocol (IP) addresses, the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) accessed (which may reference the name of a board, card, username, or team), and the unique identification number associated with the account. We don't use that information to identify you, with one exception: we may discover, by reviewing log files, that a particular account is using the Services in a way that is degrading the experience for all the Services’ users. If this is discovered, we may look up personally identifiable information associated with that account in order to contact the account owner. We handle and disclose this information in the same way we handle other potentially personally identifying information as described below.